# How to create a table of Color items in Java

Tags: java, colors

How can I create a table of Color elements like below ?

```
private Color[] = {Color.black, Color.darkGray, Color.gray, Color.lightGray, Color.pink, Color.orange, Color.cyan, Color.yellow, Color.magenta};
```

Comment: What kind of table? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe you give your object a name, like `private Color[] colors = // and so on`?!

Comment: The code above doesn't work and I don't know why, how can I create a list/table of Colors that works ?

Comment: @maximus_de, yes it worked, sorry for the question :(

Comment: @user3569631, thats fine. No matter for the question. Sometimes it happens to miss the easiest things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In respect to your comment, your problem is that you have not correctly initialized your variable, in fact you forgot to name it.

Use

```
private Color[] colors = {Color.black, Color.darkGray, Color.gray, Color.lightGray, Color.pink, Color.orange, Color.cyan, Color.yellow, Color.magenta};
```

instead of your's and you can use your array.